# Thread leak on Apache Camel asyncRequestBodyAndHeaders

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

Apache-camel version:2.10

I’m generating async request to endpoint using below Apache camel template producer.
We are acknowledged thread leak on multiple concurrent consumer for `template.asyncRequestBodyAndHeaders()`
Please let me know how we avoid the thread leak
Note: There is no thread leak with single thread

[ref_document:](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.1/html/Apache_Camel_Development_Guide/Templates.html)

```
template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
Future<Object> result = template.asyncRequestBodyAndHeaders(endpoint, sendMessage, httpClient);
```

Comment: Could please help someboady, is possible bug in Apache camel 2.10